# Django 1.9 - makemigrations/migrate on Heroku does not create relation

Tags: django, heroku, django-migrations

I am trying to deploy my 1.9 Django project to Heroku, but have problems with applying my migrations. After running 'python manage.py migrate', all tables are created expect for one relation that is used for a many-to-many relationship. It is defined as follows:

```
class CardInJar(models.Model):
   card = models.ForeignKey(ContentCard)
   jar = models.ForeignKey(MessageJar)
   seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   class Meta:
      auto_created = True
```

I've already tried making the migrations locally and commiting them, and making them on the server, resetting the database in between. After migrating, all other tables are created and are working correctly. When I try to use the CardInJar relation however, I get a `relation "YourShoeBox_cardinjar" does not exist` error. The local app works perfectly.

**EDIT:**

Because it was asked, the full traceback:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "YourShoeBox_cardinjar" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ar"."jar_id", "YourShoeBox_cardinjar"."seen" FROM "YourShoeB...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  92.         return super(PermissionRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
  116.         context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)

File "/app/src/YourShoeBox/views.py" in get_context_data
  158.         context['random_unseen_card'] = get_random_unseen(context["object"])

File "/app/src/YourShoeBox/views.py" in get_random_unseen
  133.     for message in jar.cardinjar_set.all():

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  256.         self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1085.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  835.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /jar/1/
Exception Value: relation "YourShoeBox_cardinjar" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ar"."jar_id", "YourShoeBox_cardinjar"."seen" FROM "YourShoeB..
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager


# Create your models here.
class ContentCard(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, related_name="creator")

class ImageCard(ContentCard):
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)

    def render(self):
        return self.title, self.message


class TextCard(ContentCard):
    mood = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=" ")


class VideoCard(ContentCard):
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)


class MessageJar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(ContentCard, through="CardInJar", blank=True)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, related_name="to_user")
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, related_name="from_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " | to: " + str(self.to_user)



class CardInJar(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(ContentCard)
    jar = models.ForeignKey(MessageJar)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        auto_created = True
```

Comment: Can you post full trace back and you model.py

Comment: Why are you using `auto_created = True`? This is an internal attribute, you shouldn't touch it.

Comment: Removing it solved it. I don't remember why I added it, I must've seen it in some example code. Thanks.